# How to normalize Persian texts with Hazm

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, persian

I have a folder containing some other *folders* and each contains a lot of text files. I have to extract **5 words** before and after a specific word and following code works fine.

The problem is that because I did not normalize the texts, it just returns a few sentences while there is more. 
In Persian there is a module called **hazm** for normalizing the texts. How can I use that in this code?

For example of normalizing: **"ك"**  should change to **"ک"** or **"ؤ"** should change to "و". Because the first two ones are actually *Arabic* alphabets which were used in *Persian*. Without normalizing the code just returns the words that are written with the second form and it does not recognize the words which are in the first forms *Arabic*).

```
import os
from hazm import Normalizer


def getRollingWindow(seq, w):
    win = [next(seq) for _ in range(11)]
    yield win
    for e in seq:
        win[:-1] = win[1:]
        win[-1] = e
        yield win


def extractSentences(rootDir, searchWord):
    with open("پاکت", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        for root, _dirs, fnames in os.walk(rootDir):
            for fname in fnames:
                print("Looking in", os.path.join(root, fname))
                with open(os.path.join(root, fname), encoding = "utf-8") as infile:
                    #normalizer = Normalizer()
                    #fname = normalizer.normalize(fname)
                    for window in getRollingWindow((word for line in infile for word in line(normalizer.normalize(line)).split()), 11):
                        if window[5] != searchWord: continue
                        outfile.write(' '.join(window)+ "\n")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't experience with **Hazm**, but it is easy to normalize it yourself with the following piece of code.
(Note that here we just replace Arabic character with Persian)

```
def clean_sentence(sentence):
    sentence = arToPersianChar(sentence)
    sentence = arToPersianNumb(sentence)
    # more_normalization_function()
    return sentence


def arToPersianNumb(number):
    dic = {
        '١': '۱',
        '٢': '۲',
        '٣': '۳',
        '٤': '۴',
        '٥': '۵',
        '٦': '۶',
        '٧': '۷',
        '٨': '۸',
        '٩': '۹',
        '٠': '۰',
    }
    return multiple_replace(dic, number)


def arToPersianChar(userInput):
    dic = {
        'ك': 'ک',
        'دِ': 'د',
        'بِ': 'ب',
        'زِ': 'ز',
        'ذِ': 'ذ',
        'شِ': 'ش',
        'سِ': 'س',
        'ى': 'ی',
        'ي': 'ی'
}
return multiple_replace(dic, userInput)


def multiple_replace(dic, text):
    pattern = "|".join(map(re.escape, dic.keys()))
    return re.sub(pattern, lambda m: dic[m.group()], str(text))
```

Just you need to read each line of your document and pass it to `clean_sentence()`:

```
def clean_all(document):
    clean = ''
    for sentence in document:
        sentence = clean_sentence(sentence)
        clean += ' \n' + sentence
    return clean
```

Comment: It is simple and clear but adding  ' \n' is not always needed.